# Print table in freemarker/html if value exists in table

Tags: html, freemarker

Doing a PDF design in an ERP system. The design tool is a combination of HTML and Freemarker. I want to add a table if any of the order's orderlines has a value in a specific field greater than 0, and the table data shall only consist of these lines. It looks like this now:

```
    <#if order.item?has_content>
    <table class="itemtable" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th colspan="8">Item</th>
        <th align="right" colspan="3">Quantity</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
      
      <#list salesorder.item as tranline><#if tranline.quantity!=0>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="8">{tranline.item}</td>
                <td align="right" colspan="3">${tranline.quantity}</td>
                            
                
            </tr>
                                        </#if> 
                  </#list>
                    
        </table>
       </#if>
```

--

So, the table contains only of the lines that has quantity > 0, which is the result I want. But I also want the table head to be printed only if my condition is OK. Now, if none of the orderlines has quantity > 0, the table head is created with no lines. I don't want it to appear at all in that case.

Really simple thing I would guess, but I'm a newbie.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

SO, I just want to do something like:

IF MAX(Order.Quantity) > 0 THEN .... create table

Comment: Please next time edit the question if you have clarifications, instead of adding an answer. Anyway to calculate that value you could use `objs?map(order -> order.quantity)?max`, but as my answer will show, you don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping this is not Netsuite (which uses a modified variant of some old FreeMarker version), you can use `?filter`, combined with `#list`+`#items` (see  https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html#ref.directive.items):

```
<#list salesorder.item?filter(order -> order.quantity != 0)>
  <table>
    <thead>...</thead>
    <#items as order>
      <tr>... print order data here
    </#items>
  <table>
</#list>
```

Under Netsuite, if `?filter` is still not supported when you read this, you could loop twice. In the first loop check if there's any line that satisfies the condition, but print nothing, and then only if there was a match, do a second loop that prints the items:

```
<#assign hasMatchingOrder = false>
<#list salesorder.item as order>
  <#if order.quantity != 0>
    <#assign hasMatchingOrder = true>
    <#break>
  </#if>
</#list>
<#if hasMatchingOrder>
  <table>
    <thead>...</thead>
    <#list salesorder.item as order>
      <#if order.quantity != 0>
        <tr>... print order data here
      </#if>
    </#list>
  </table>
</#if>
```

So this is much uglier and error-prone to do, so please pester Oracle to update FreeMarker in Netsuite.

Otherwise, if things like above is often needed, then it can be put into a macro, although I don't know if Netsuite supports templates having shared macros (that is, a shared `#include`-ed or `#importe`-ed files).

Comment: Hi! It is Netsuite :D Could you please show me that double loop? Thank you very much!

Comment: Netsuite... then I have updated my answer

Comment: Thank you very much, worked like a charm!